# Error while deleting from CTE

Tags: sql, db2

```
with CTE AS
(
    select AGENT_USERID,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY AGENT_USERID ORDER BY (agent_USERID)) AS RN
    FROM KYCKEN.PAP_KYCAGENTCONFIG
)
DELETE FROM CTE where RN > 1
```

I am getting error that from statement is required while running the query. There is no code before that. Using the query to delete duplicates. Select in place of delete is working fine but while using the delete throwing error.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Do you have any statement before this one in your script?

Comment: That is invalid standard SQL. Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Tried in both sql server and DB2 also. Getting same error.

Answer (score 1):

Db2 for Linux/Unix/Windows accepts the syntax below:

```
with cte as
  (
    select agent_userid
          ,row_number() over (partition by agent_userid order by (agent_userid)) as rn
    from kycken.pap_kycagentconfig
  )
select agent_userid as agent_userid_to_delete 
from old table
  ( delete from kycken.pap_kycagentconfig
    where agent_userid in (select agent_userid from cte where rn > 1) 
  )
;
```

Comment: Thanx let me try the same

Answer (score 0):

On DB2, try Something like this :

```
DELETE FROM KYCKEN.PAP_KYCAGENTCONFIG f0
where rrn(f0) in 
(
  select f2.rnwrite 
  from  (
            select f1.AGENT_USERID, rrn(f1) rnwrite, 
            ROWNUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY f1.AGENT_USERID ORDER BY f1.agent_USERID) AS RN
            FROM KYCKEN.PAP_KYCAGENTCONFIG f1
        ) f2 
  where f2.RN>1

)
```